# Cannot initialize the indexer process on Category Products

Tags: magento-1.9

i am finding issue but still same (flat_products) resolve issue. i try to solve this issue befor 3 days please help me how can i resolve this issue [image]

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`techfors_tfs`.`catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`enti), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product_index` (`category_id`, `product_id`, `position`, `is_parent`, `store_id`, `visibility`) SELECT `catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`category_id`, `catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`product_id`,

Comment: Magento 1 Try this Using SSH ( php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_category )

Answer (score 0):

Visit the below link then try reindexing

http://support.createhosting.co.nz/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=70